# Help converting Json into a Dynamic Map

Tags: apex, json

I need to convert this json

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "hostgroup.get",
    "params": {
        "output": "extend",
        "filter": {
            "name": [
                "4:CLIENTES.Balearia"
            ]
        }
    },
    "auth": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "id": 1
}
```

into a Map like this:

```
   String payload = JSON.serialize(
        new Map<String, Object> { 
            'jsonrpc' => '2.0',
                'method' => 'hostgroup.get',
                'params' => 
                new Map<String, Object> {
                    'output' => 'extend',
                    'filter' => new Map<String[], String>{'name' => '4:CLIENTES.Balearia'}
                },
                    'auth' => result,
                    'id' => 1
                    }
    );
```

So I can play with the values and make them dynamic before sending them to the webservice.

I've been trying but always an error .... Is there any tool for making this ??

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like this:

```
String payload = JSON.serialize(
    new Map<String, Object> { 
        'jsonrpc' => '2.0',
            'method' => 'hostgroup.get',
            'params' => 
            new Map<String, Object> {
                'output' => 'extend',
                'filter' => new Map<String, String[]>{'name' => new String[] { '4:CLIENTES.Balearia' } }
            },
                'auth' => result,
                'id' => 1
                }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [json2apex](http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) to create a serializable class, but it can only create static classes. To be dynamic, you need to write it by hand. There's only so much that a tool can help you with. You need to understand the basics of data models. In your code, you wrote `Map<String[], String>`, which would be a `List<String>` for the key, but you should have written `Map<String, String>`. You should read more about [Lists](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_lists.htm), [Maps](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_maps.htm), and [Sets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_sets.htm) for more information.

Comment: Yup, now I figured it out ... I'm not new with programming (2-3 years) but this is difficultttt hahahaha .... sorry for the stupid question ;(    and many thanks as always